# Fixing No PolicyContextHandler for key=javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse exception

Tags: java, jsf, cookies, response, jboss5.x

Am using Jboss 5.1.0

In my bean, I want to get `Response` object and using this I want to set some values back to the `cookie`.

Below is my code in bean,

```
HttpServletResponse response = null;
response = (HttpServletResponse) PolicyContext.getContext("javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse"); 
//Line number 1230


HttpServletRequest req = null;
req = (HttpServletRequest) PolicyContext.getContext("javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest");

Cookie[] cookies =  req.getCookies();

for(int i=0;i<cookies.length;i++)
 {
   if(cookies[i].getName().contains("myCookie"))
                {
                    cookies[i].setValue("");
                    cookies[i].setPath("/");
                    cookies[i].setMaxAge(0);
                    response.addCookie(cookies[i]);
                }
}
```

But, am getting below exception at line number 1230

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No PolicyContextHandler for key=javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
13:24:16,457 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.security.jacc.PolicyContext.getContext(PolicyContext.java:107)
13:24:16,457 ERROR [STDERR]     at myPackage.myBean(myBean.java:1230)
13:24:16,457 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
13:24:16,457 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
13:24:16,457 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
13:24:16,457 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
13:24:16,457 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:170)
13:24:16,457 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
13:24:16,457 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:68)
13:24:16,457 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
13:24:16,457 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
13:24:16,457 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:387)
13:24:16,457 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:329)
13:24:16,457 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEventsForPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:304)
13:24:16,457 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:261)
```

Am getting `request` object but not `response` object. How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `PolicyContext` is unnecessary in managed beans. In managed beans you have already direct access to `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` via [`ExternalContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html).

```
ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();
// ...
```

The `PolicyContext` is only useful in service classes like EJBs where you don't directly have access to them. Your concrete problem is caused because the `PolicyContext` simply doesn't remember the HTTP servlet response, but only the HTTP servlet request, because the information about the currently logged-in user is stored in there. In essence, the HTTP servlet response is irrelevant to policy context.

Note that the `ExternalContext` also offers a convenient [`getRequestCookieMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestCookieMap%28%29) method which returns a mapping of all cookies so that you don't need to manually traverse the `Cookie[]`.

```
Cookie cookie = (Cookie) externalContext.getRequestCookieMap().get("myCookie");
// ...
```

I know that you're using JSF 1.2, but if you were using JSF 2.0 or newer, then you could also have used the convenient [`addResponseCookie()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#addResponseCookie%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%29) method to add a cookie without the need to obtain the "raw" servlet response.

Comment: `HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();`    Works!   :)